# Why regex is not working?

Tags: python, regex, cyrillic

I need to replace all occurences of normal whitespaces in «статья 1», «статьи 2» etc. with non-breaking spaces. 
The construction below works fine:

```
 re.sub('(стат.{0,4}) (\d+)', r'\1&#x00A0;\2', text) # 'r' in repl is important, otherwise the word is not replaced correctly, at least for texts in Russian.
```

however, I do not want to repeatedly use `re.sub` for «статья», then for «пункт», then for the names of months, I want to have a dictionary with regex expressions and replacements. Here's my code, but it does not work as expected: `'статья 1 статьи 2'` should look like `'статья(non-breaking space here)1 статьи(non-breaking space here)2'`:

```
 import re

 text = 'статья 1 статьи 2'
 dic = {'(cтат.{0,4}) (\d+)' : r'\1&#x00A0;\2'}


 def replace():
     global text
     final_text = ''
     for i in dic:
         new_text = re.sub(str(i), str(dic[i]), text)
         text = new_text
     return text

 print (replace())
```

Comment: Hopefully this is Python 3.x? If not, you have multiple problems.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a `final_text` variable, then replacing a global instead of using it, and then returning the global?

Comment: Also, you want the `r` prefix on the regexp pattern, not just the replacement pattern. You happen to get away with it here because `\d` happens to mean `'\\d'` in Python, but you should never count on that.

Comment: Finally, why are you doing `str(i)` and `str(dic[i])`? Are you expecting `i` and `dic[i]` to be something other than strings? Or trying to make an extra copy of them? Or…?

Comment: If I don't use str(), I and getting TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern. Yes, it's Python 3. I am quite new to Python, so my code may look pretty foolish, however, I am trying to iterate over my dictinary and use key as a pattern and dic[key] as a repl.

Comment: If you don't use the `str`, it works just fine. [Here's proof](http://ideone.com/VnkZBe)—that's just your code without the `str` calls, and it runs. You must be doing something different in your actual code than what you showed us here if you're getting that `TypeError`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you copied and pasted wrong.

This pattern works:

```
'(стат.{0,4}) (\d+)'
```

This one doesn't:

```
'(cтат.{0,4}) (\d+)'
```

Why? Because in the first one, and in your search string, that first character is a U+0441, a Cyrillic small Es. But in the second one, it's a U+0063, a Latin small C. Of course the two look identical in most fonts, but they're not the same character.

---

So, how can you tell? Well, when I suspected this problem, here's what I did:

```
>>> a = '(стат.{0,4}) (\d+)' # copied and pasted from your working code
>>> b = '(cтат.{0,4}) (\d+)' # copied and pasted from your broken code
>>> print(a.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii'))
(\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0442.{0,4}) (\\d+)
>>> print(b.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii'))
(c\u0442\u0430\u0442.{0,4}) (\\d+)
```

And the difference is obvious: the first one has a `\u0441` escape sequence where the second one has a plain ASCII `c`.

Comment: I got it, however, the code is not working properly in GUI, due to some other reasons, I suppose... http://pastebin.com/vBnFuuyP

Comment: UPD: Sure, I am searching for «стат.» but the text I check contains «Стат.» only! Thank you once again!